# Query Returns diffrent result When datatype is time

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns where data type is as below

[image]

and fired below query

[image]

which returns below result

[image]

and if i run below query 
[image]

then return different result as below

[image]

i just wondering why this comes?

I am using SQL SERVER 2008